# DAO method - rs.update with an option group

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am using `rs.update` to change some values. something like

```
rs("SomeField") = frmSomeOptionGroup.value
```

where I want the actual option value to be stored in the table. However, this just simply seems to return `true` or `false` values to the table instead of `0-2`.

What should I do to make this concept work?

Comment: What is "frmSomeOptionGroup"? A control on a form? If so, what form? What's the context of your code? In the form's module or elsewhere? Why have you not just bound the option group to the field you're trying to update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept should work. Can you set a breakpoint and check the value of the option group?

Comment: it does work. it was a problem with the table having fields orginally set to true/false, and the defaults for those fields had a value of -1. In order to make the above work, the data type of those fields were set to number vs. yes/no, but it didn't work until I realized there were default values, and changed those to nothing. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should use rs.update with rs.requery

Comment: Why requery? If you're updating in SQL a value that's displayed on your form, you might need to refresh the form to show the updated value, but a requery of the recordset after an update would serve no purpose insofar as the question being asked (it might be useful for other reasons not mentioned).